# Identifying a link in selenium (no id or class provided)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I would like to know how to identify via webdriver the following html "node":

```
<a href="http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=2&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=0CDAQFjAB&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fpl.glosbe.com%2Fen%2Fpl%2Fthank%2520you%2520very%2520much%2520indeed&amp;ei=OSO8U7GADqeV7AacroDYCQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNG4ELDFcZgL9gKbm2UV96aHCnjvRg" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNG4ELDFcZgL9gKbm2UV96aHCnjvRg','','0CDAQFjAB','','',event)">thank you <em>very much indeed</em> - Angielsko-Polski Słownik <b>...</b></a>
```

(It's just any link of google when one launch a google search)

I have googled it, however I have found only cases where the id or the class were provided. 
What about in this case?

This is my failing try:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpl.bab.la%2Fslownik%2Fangielski-polski%2Fthank-you-very-much-indeed&ei=Sia8U6LPCevB7AagwoCICg&usg=AFQjCNF6y7swYrp3axD0hNrCWfjovhcVPw&bvm=bv.70138588,d.bGE']")).click();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `By.linkText()` or `By.partialLinkText()`, if you know the text in advance.  Failing that, if you add more HTML, we can help you with a selector.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities:

```
By.tagName("a")
```

However, chances are there are more than one `a` tag, and so the above will pick the first one it encounters. To get more specific, you can use:

```
By.xpath("//a[0]")
```

`0` in this case refers explicitly to the first `a` tag. However, to give a precise XPath answer, I would need to see more your page code, as well as your exact requirements. You can also use:

```
By.partialLinkText("thank you very much indeed")
```

This works best if you have unique enclosed text.

You may also want to read through the rest of the locators in [the API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/By.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to identify the the link directly, you can try based on other element.

When you have any adjacent div or element having unique value, you can refer the link relative to that.

```
WebElemenet element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#id a"));
```

This will get the link element which is present in the div having an id value of "id".